# Attach Selenium Chrome webdriver to already opened browser window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

For example some user launched his browser, then he launched my program. I need to interact with this browser (not necessarily Chrome).
Is there a solution for my problem in *Selenium*? Or in another way?

1) I saw the almost suitable way. It is to launch Chrome from Command Prompt by this command:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\selenum\ChromeProfile"
```

And then to attach launched browser in code like this:

```
# PYTHON Example
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:1234")
#Change chrome driver path accordingly
chrome_driver = "C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But this is a **manually** launched browser

2) Or the second way at this [link](http://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/). But there is problem from the first try.

3) In this [issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18) on GitHub I found [this class](https://gist.github.com/dnedbaylo/852560), but it doesn't work for me. In the issue was written that it was tested only with Firefox (on ubuntu).

Is there a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very hacky solution considering Software development practices but here goes..

Once you initiate Google chrome manually or with a script, you can interact with that using PyAutoGUI module. We can move the mouse to a position on the screen, click and then type.

An example code after opening chrome :

```
import pyautogui, time
pyautogui.PAUSE = 2

# x and y is the mouse position on your screen    
pyautogui.moveTo(x=410, y=79)
pyautogui.click()
# select all
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.press(['delete'])
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite("https://google.com")
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: Ok. As I understand it, this is the only solution at the moment. I will try this. Thanks